# Symfony .env security

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony4

I would like to secure my symfony project.
And I saw that, in my .env file, the line with the connection to the database:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/my_db
```

I think it is not secure because the username and password are in clear.
Could you tell me how to secure my connection to the database and how to hide the connection information or how to securize them ?

Cordially

Comment: If your `.env` file is not accessible via web - it's okay to store data as is.

Comment: your webserver should be set to handle the public subdir as root, so from the web, nobody should be able to access the .env file. Besides the point, you should define the data inside the .env file via server environment variables (depends on webserver used), which would even further reduce the attack surface. there might be weak reasons for the .env file to exist (mainly bin/console availability)

Comment: @Jakumi could you give an example how to config the .env filie with server environment variables?

Comment: @Frank B - define them in PHP-FPM pool config for example (see bottom of file) -  it all depends on your system and how good/limited your access to the server is.

Comment: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-deployment/video/symfony-4-environment-variable-tutorial (text contains all necessary information)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing bad in `.env` file. Here are two documentation articles about: [configuring environment variables in production](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production) and [configure environment variables during deploy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables).

Just make sure that **only `public` dir** is accessible from web.

As it said in docs your can define environment variables on server side using linux environment variables. But this is pretty tricky. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) can help you. Still if someone get access to your server files he can steal your password for database just using [`getenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function. I'm not sure that this method is more secure.

I think that key thing is a CI/CD script. You must not keep production `.env` file in your repo. Instead you should add this file during deploy process. Environment variables must be stored in secured place, for example I'm using [gitlab's environment variables storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) and creating `.env` file [during deploy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/).

Also check your [database privileges](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.design.php). Probably this is the best method to minimize harm from loosing password to database.